# Barplot/histogram using frequencies in R

Tags: r, histogram, axis

Suppose you have two vectors, where the first vector is a vector of values a variable takes, and second is the probability (frequency) of this value. It should look like this:

```
 a <- c(2.1,7.5,5.2,6,5.8)
 b <- c(1/8,1/8,1/3,5/24,5/24)
```

I have a lot of those combinations of vectors. Suppose values in all `a` vectors are in range from 1 to 10.

What i need is two different graphs:

- First is a barplot/histogram of values of `a` based on frequencies `b` (so heights of bars are equal to frequencies), and values on x axis include only the ordered values of `a`,
- second is a similar graph, but on x axis should be all possible values of  `a` vectors - so the axis should be from 1 to 10 and the bars should only be  above the relevant values of `a`.

In both cases bars should have same width. My question is: How to plot these graphs?

I really think that what I want is called histogram but before I posted this question I made research on this web, and I became very confused about bar plots and histograms.

Comment: `barplot(b[order(a)], names.arg=sort(a)) ; hist(rep(a, b*24), breaks=20, xlim=c(0,10), axes=FALSE);  axis(1, labels=0:10, at=0:10)`. (imo fwit) a histogram seems a bit more appropraite here (as your x-xis variable appears to be continuous rather than discrete)

Comment: Thx a lot, but your hist shouldnt work for all frequencies, since you cant always transform a percentage to a integer. It is the whole problem. But thx a lot again.